# Installing Python 3.4 and setting up additional libraries

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently setting up a development environment on my MacBook (Mac OS X 10.6.8).  I'm deciding between versions 2.7 and 3.4 of Python to start learning from.  However, before I decide on a version I have a question about external libraries.  I want to learn NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib, etc.

My question is:  Do the external libraries (NumPy for example) require a specific version of python in order to run correctly?  If so, how do I tell if a library requires 2.7 or 3.4?

I don't want to choose a certain version of python only to find out that the libraries I downloaded won't work.  Please help me!

Comment: To see what versions of Python a given library supports, you go to the web page for that library and see what it says.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://python3wos.appspot.com/) packages you want, work in python 3.

Comment: My suggestion is to install the [Anaconda Python distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), as it takes care of much of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each external library you are looking at using should specify what version(s) of Python it works with. For example, looking quickly at the NumPy docs, it appears that you need to have Python 2.4.x-2.6.x: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/user/install.html

If you know in advanced what libraries you want to use, I can pretty much guarantee that any library worth using will tell you what version of Python it requires without too much searching in the documentation.

You also might want to think about having multiple version of python installed on your machine. For example, having 2.7.x and 3.4.x available concurrently, and using that appropriate version of python for the libraries you are working with. Although you'll need to make sure that you have the libraries installed for the correct verion(s) that you are working with.